# QT 5.9 with VS 2017 - getting unresolved symbols with QWebEngineView

Tags: c++, qt, linker-errors

I'm foraying into C++ and QT 5.9.

I'm running QT Tools for VS 2017 with QT 5.9 libraries added to VS 2017 and am building QT GUI applications without issue.

However, when I try to build a *very* simple example that invloves QWebEngineView or QWebEnginePage, I'm geting unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)...on QWebEngineView...
I've also noticed that a few of the #includes don't match the examples on the QT 5.9 doc site...

I've uninstalled and re-installed QT 5.9 and also 5.6 a few times and included every module I could into each, just in case!

Code

```
#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWebEngineWidgets/QtWebEngineWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWebEngineView view;
    view.show();
    view.load(QUrl("http://google.com"));

    return a.exec();
}
```

Build Output

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QWebEngineView::QWebEngineView(class QWidget *)" (__imp_??0QWebEngineView@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl QWebEngineView::~QWebEngineView(void)" (__imp_??1QWebEngineView@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QWebEngineView::load(class QUrl const &)" (__imp_?load@QWebEngineView@@QEAAXAEBVQUrl@@@Z) referenced in function main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the QtWebEngine library to the linker. Open the qmake .pro file and add `QT += webenginewidgets`. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html

Comment: Thanks for this, however if I'm reading it right, Visual Studio doesn't recognise .pro files?

Comment: Yes, but the QT tools for VS do understand them and can convert from .pro to VS project.

Comment: Ah! Thank you very nuch